# float effect using vertical-align applied to table cells

Tags: css

I've found out that setting `display` property of containing block to `table` and enclosing descendant block boxes in boxes with `display` property set to `table-cell` and `vertical-align` property set to `top` has same effect as if `float` property of those boxes was set to `left`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>simulating float</title>
<style type="text/css">

#container {
background-color: darkgrey;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
height: 240px;
display: table;
}

.box {
margin: 5px;
width: 240px;
height: 240px;
background-color: grey;
}

.float {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div class="float">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="float">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="float">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone give me an explanation of this? Thanks.

Comment: This has very useful side effect: boxes do not quit floating when resizing viewport as it happens when `float` property is used.

Answer (score 0):

The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Also, `display:table-cell` makes the element behave like the  HTML tag.
The `vertical-align:top` propriety makes the element aligned to the top of the entire line or align the top padding edge of the cell with the top of the row. So the

`.float {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
}`

looks like if it had `float:left` only.

I hope this will help you understand CSS better.